# Convert one store Ubercart in two stores

Tags: ubercart

I have installed Ubercart in Drupal 6.  The client likes that the actual store be converted in two stores and that each store has its own administration.

Is it possible?  or have to I create a drupal separated for each store?.

Many thanks for your answers.